# Restrict function inputs to the given regex format

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, npm, ecmascript-6

I have a function that accepts one input, an array, that can have X number of values. I have a string, which indicates the final format desired.

Example:

```
function doFormat(args) {
  const format = 'Foo \\d{1,2}x\\d{2} Bar';
}

doFormat([123, 2, 3]);
```

Let's assume, for now, that `format` will only contain a regex pattern that matches numbers with `\\d`, and that inputs will only contain numbers.

In this specific example, I want to coerce the input args into the string `Foo 12x02 Bar`, as required by the `format` variable, because the first match of `\\d{1,2}` restricts it to an integer with a maximum length of 2 (therefore trimming the first input, from `123` to just `12`), and the second match of `\\d{2}` restricts to an integer with a length of exactly 2 (therefore padding the second input, from `2` to `02`). And we drop the third input of `3`, because it isn't used in `format`.

How can I achieve this? I'm using this in a Node script run on a server, so I can use any NPM packages, if necessary.

Comment: Your function does not use the argument (and it returns nothing).

Comment: Because I'm asking how to do it. The function doesn't do anything right now. I'm trying to get it to generate the output specified, given the `args` input and the `format`. I can remove the example if that would help...

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You have to be more specific of what you intend to accomplish.

Comment: Do you need your specific example (numbers with length) or can `format` be any valid regex? The latter sounds hard and my gut tells me it's also NP-complete

Comment: Let's assume that only numbers will be used as inputs. I'll try and figure out letters, later.

Comment: The issue is not between numbers and letters but with different constructs that can appear in regex. This is basically "here is a regex and some variables, take the static part of the regex and the variables and create a string so that it conforms to the regex and the parser encounters the variables in array order". If it's just replacing some `\\d{1,2}` with the next variable from the array, that is some formatting work but not at all on the level of the generic case.

Comment: Okay, if we were to simply take the case of `\\d{1,2}`, how would I extract this from `format`, then coerce the first input of `123` to satisfy this regex?

Comment: That's reversing regex. If you want to deal with digits only, this would be possible but not a general solution.

Comment: @revo i think it should be possible either way, the general solution just sounds very NP-complete. If the regex isn't complex or the array short, it should even compute in a manageable timespan.

Comment: So perhaps it's best if I use a different format, like `format = 'Foo {1}x{2} Bar'; args = [ { type: 'number', minLength: 1, maxLength 2 }, { type: 'number', length: 2 ]` and just do this without any regex at all?

Comment: The first parser i would think of for the special case would not care at all that your syntax is regex but be written from scratch and just look for patterns. Therefore a different format might be preferred - yes. Here is a demo: `let arr = [123, 2, 3], k = arr.keys(); 'Foo \\d{1,2}x\\d{2} Bar'.replace(/\\d\{(\d)(,\d)?\}/g, (m, p1, p2) => arr[k.next().value].toString().substr(0, p2 ? +p2.substr(1) : +p1));` - note that this e.g. only looks for single digits and omits a lot of error handling (e.g. not enough numbers in array), i had to cram it into a comment afterall (not really a full answer).

Comment: Is string format value is required or it can be template string?

Comment: @PashaRumkin Template string is fine.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Okay thanks I will try that code out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created npm package named `to-fmt` which uses literal templates to produce new string renderer function.

For your case it can work like so:

```
import f from 'to-fmt';

// Number formatter function
const num = (...args) => value => {
    let start;
    let end;

    const str = String(value);

    if (args.length > 1) {
        start = args[0];
        end = start + args[1];
    }
    else if (args.length) {
        start = 1;
        end = 1 + args[0];
    }
    else {
        start = 1;
        end = str.length;
    }

    const len = end - start;

    return str.slice(start - 1, end - 1)
    .padStart(len, '0')
    .slice(-len);
};

// Create new format:
const format = f`Foo ${num(1, 2)}x${num(2)} Bar`;

format(123, 2, 3); // -> 'Foo 12x02 Bar'
// And if you want to pass an Array
format(...[123, 2, 3]); // -> 'Foo 12x02 Bar'
```

Using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) it is possible to create custom string formatters (and whatever you want). Provided package uses this to produce new function. It requires placeholders to be a functions which can convert values to strings.